# error : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CAlerteModel'

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have searched in the Net a solution to this problem, but, haven't found what can fix this error. I have marked the line (CDB.h) from which the error comes.

CDB.h

```
class CDB{
public:
    CDB(); //ctor
    virtual ~CDB(); //dtor

    virtual void ajouterAlerte(CAlerteModel); // marked
    virtual void ajouterFichier(CFichierModel);
    virtual LISTSTR getListeAppsMetiers();
};
```

CDB.cpp

```
#include "CDB.h"
void CDB::ajouterAlerte(CAlerteModel cam){
    // code code code
}
```

Is the problem comes from the function's prototype ?

Any brilliant idea, please ?

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you "what the heck is a 'CAlerteModel'?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a file, where `CAlerteModel` is declared (or declare it on your own, but I guess, you want to use Code from somebody else).
Otherwise, the compiler cannot know, how this datatype looks like.

Answer (score 0):

include the header file which contains the declaration of CAlerteModel in CDB.h. Also, include the header file which has the declaration of CFichierModel.

Answer (score -1):

The code you showed is irrelevant because we do not see the definition of identifier `CAlerteModel`
I only can suppose that instead of `CAlerteModel` maybe you should use `CAlertModel` that is maybe you made a typo provided that  all appropriate headers are included.

Comment: Doubtful. The identifiers are in French, and `Alerte` is the proper French.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit I pointed the direction of searching the reason of the error. It is not necessary that the identifier shall be the same as I pointed out. Nevertheless there may be a typo.

Comment: Please, write `@LightnessRacesinOrbit` (no spaces) when you reply, as otherwise I do not get a notification. I stumbled upon your reply only by chance. In fact if you type `@Lig` a popup appears which enables you to tab-complete the respondee.